# Create a well-formed record on mobile entry form when the record spans more than one table

Tags: mysql, mobile

In my mobile app I have an entry screen with 10 fields. The business owners want the user to be able to enter all the fields when creating the record. The first 9 fields are normal fields in a primary table. The last field is an attachment that is stored in a child table.

The programmers are saying that the user will only be able to enter the first nine fields initially. They must create the record, which generates the unique key for the primary record, and only then can the update the record by adding an attachment.

They claim that since we haven't created a primary key on the parent record, there is no way they can allow the user to save the attachment until that is done. Hence the user has to save the record, then go back in and add the attachment and then save again.

I am thinking that this should be done within the save logic itself. When the user saves upon creation, the save operation first writes out the parent record [and runs any necessary edits and kicks back an error if validation fails] and then grabs the unique id just created, and writes out to the child table with this key and the attachment.

Out pattern BTW is offline first, so we always write to the local SQL before going back to the server, so that won't be a problem.

Am I missing anything?

that the save operation for a new record with all 10 fields entered would

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not missing anything.

The save logic (server-side) should:

1. insert the primary row
2. get its generated id using `LAST_INSERT_ID()`
3. use that last id in a subsequent insert to the child table.

Developers do this all the time, in any programming language.

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. Karwin.

Comment: I think I understand what their concern is now.

Comment: I'm curious, what is their concern? What's the problem with the above solution?

Comment: I asked yesterday morning. In the (current) UI the user must push a button to bring up a dialog box and then attach the file in the dialog box and then save from there. So that UI dictated how they approached the backend operations. Since it worked they didn't want to change it. When I said it was important to the business owners that they can enter all data on create, and that clicking a button to bring up the dialog box just added an extra click, they said they would change it.